# Extending TelephonyManager, Sub-classing with @hide constructors

Tags: java, android, unit-testing

I am trying to get to where I can write a unit test for the following line of code:

```
devicePhoneNumber = ((TelephonyManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getLine1Number();
```

I am trying to wrapper some of these calls to the application context so that I isolate them and unit test them with my own classes.

So I look at this line, and my idea is that I should create my own MockTelephonyManager that extends TelephonyManager, then place this in a map for my MockApplicationContext and have it return my Mock object instead of the actual one.

The problem is that all of the constructors for TelephonyManager have @hide annotations, so my subclasses can't instantiate the parent.

(This, by the way, is why constructors should be protected, but not private. :()

I know that the constructors would still be visible to reflection, but can't figure out how to do that and make my subclass still be a TelephonyManager. I looked into proxies, but they seem to only work for interfaces.

I wondered how others were handling this.

Comment: I would use composition instead of inheritance. Have `MockTelephonyManager` hold a `TelephonyManager` and pass along methods of relevance.

Comment: @CommonsWare I've certainly thought about that, but if MockTelephonyManager does not extend TelephonyManager, the cast will fail.

Comment: :: smacks forehead :: -- you are absolutely correct, my apologies.

Comment: @CommonsWare "'salright, you good kid." --Bugs Bunny